# Oracle OCI trigger creation

Tags: c, oracle, triggers, sequences, oracle-call-interface

Is there any way to create trigger using OCI API?

I need to perform the following actions programmatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tbl_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON tbl FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.id IS NULL OR new.id = 0)
BEGIN
SELECT tbl_sq.nextval INTO :new.id FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: The "pragmatic" way to do it would be to use SQL Plus not OCI!  I presume you meant "programmatically"? ;-)  But seriously, creating a trigger on a table is something you only have to do once, so why would you need to do it via an OCI API?

Comment: I, too, would do this via SQL Plus.  You can save it as a .sql file if you really need to run it more than once.  But I am not familiar with OCI, so I can't say if OCI is truely the wrong tool to use...

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to the nature of this question.

If you're asking "Can this be done?", then yes, using `OCIStmtPrepare()` and `OCIStmtExecute()`.

If you have code that attempts to do this and fails, please provide a more specific question.